# Allow certain special characters, but alphanumeric is must

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

My current Regex

```
 ^[a-zA-Z0-9\s][.,-:/\\]*$
```

But I want the user to insert at least one alphabet or numeric character too, not just the special characters.

Comment: Without valid and invalid input examples, it is a guessing game to me. FYI: `,-:` matches symbols from `,-./0123456789:` range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can done it using positive look ahead assertion, use regex **[`/^(?=.*[a-z0-9].*)[a-z0-9\s.,:\/\\-]*$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/mO3iF9/1)**

```js
var re = /^(?=.*[a-z0-9].*)[a-z0-9\s.,:\/\\-]*$/i;

$('#test').on('input', function() {
  $(this).css('color', re.test(this.value) ? 'green': 'red');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test">
```

**[Regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/mO3iF9/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 0):

with this regular expression user must insert at least one alphabet or numeric character  and the special characters.

```
^.*[a-zA-Z0-9]+.*[\.,-:/\\]+.*$
```

Answer (score 0):

So your rules are:

- Must contain zero or more alphanumeric characters
- May contain any number of whitespace characters, periods, commas, hyphens, colons, forward slashes and backslashes.

This is most easily implemented as two separate tests.

```
if (/[a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(my_string) && /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.,\-:\/\\]*$/.test(my_string))
```